# Php или Asp.net/Silverlight

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, php, joomla

Я начинающий в программировании веб сайтов, пока только десктоп-Wpf приложения на c# делал. Немного "игрался" с Jooml-ой. Что лучше выбрать Php или Asp? На wpf немного делаю и хочется это перегнать в silverlight и как-то использовать в сайтах, (возможности сильвера впечатляют и хочется как-то его использовать в сайтах... или php + silverlight, но я понял, там голову сломаешь как по мне).

Вообщем что лучше использовать php или asp? Форумы перечитал, но так и не определился, грандиозных проектов делать не буду так для себя. Может какую-то CMS посоветуете (хотя пока джумлу поставил), или что-то ещё...

Comment: Называть Asp и Asp.Net - это настолько же разные технологии, как Java и JavaScript

Comment: Читая такую охинею я часто задаю себе вопрос - почему я не люблю минусы ставить? З.Ы. минус влепил не я)

Comment: Читая охинею, я лично не обращаю внимание....или...если осведомлен в данном вопросе, попытаюсь ответить,ведь все поначалу чегото не понимают.....Я рад за тебя, что ты очень умный и родился с большими знаниями в голове...

Comment: Конкретно я в вопросе увидел не отсутствие знаний, а отсутствие логики!

Answer (score 2):

1. Silverlight - это клиентская технология, которая, как и Flash, может сопрягаться с любой серверной технологией.
2. ASP.NET и PHP - мощные зрелые технологии со своими плюсами и минусами. К примеру, Facebook, Wikipedia работают на PHP, а Microsoft и MySpace на ASP.NET.
3. Лицензировании технологий Microsoft стоит денег, а лицензировании открытого свободно распространяемого кода бесплатно, поэтому чем больше проект и чем вероятнее горизонтальное масштабирование, тем дороже лицензии, тем реже используют платный софт.

Вам, пожалуй, стоит сначала определиться с тем, что вы будете делать, узнать с помощью чего это делали другие люди до вас, и затем уже выбирать подходы.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ таков, однозначно C#, но PHP исключением не будет так как он младший брат C#. 
А суть банальна - зная PHP вы сделаете много ... визиток и простых магазинов, а зная C# + Silverlight Вы сможете сделать ВСЕ НА СВЕТЕ!